# Save data on local storage

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an app using Xamarin Forms PCL.

I want to save this class (I use this class as List in code)

```
public class TagInformation {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isJob { get; set; }
    public string _color { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public Color color { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public JobInformation jobInformation { get; set; }

    public TagInformation(Color c, string n) {
        color = c;
        _color = c.ToHex();
        name = n;
        isJob = false;
    }
    public TagInformation() {
    }
    public void setColor() {
        color = Color.FromHex(_color);
    }
}

public class JobInformation {
    public string shopName { get; set; }
    public int wage { get; set; }
    public bool isHoliday { get; set; }
    public int holidayWage { get; set; }
    public bool isMid { get; set; }
    public int midnightWage { get; set; }
    public bool[] holidayFlgs { get; set; }
    public DateTime midStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime midEnd { get; set; }
    public int tranceportCost { get; set; }
    public int closeDay { get; set; }
    public int payMentDay { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan shortRest { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan longRest { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan shortRestTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan longRestTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan commuteTime { get; set; }
    public JobInformation() {
        /* do samething */
    }
}
```

Using SQLite, this class has another class, so it doesn't work on.

Is there any other way?

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Comment: @Jason thanks I will try it!

Comment: Why don't you try using Akavache cache for Xamarin https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache It is easy to use and you don't have to care about indexing etc... Works like key, value dictonary

Comment: @Stefanjia I didn't know it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) to save it as a json string.

1.Install the **Newtonsoft.Json** nuget.

2.Serialize your class to json string and save it with a key.

```
TagInformation tarinformation = xxxxx;
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tarinformation);
Preferences.Set("your_key", jsonString);  //save the data
```

3.Retrieve a value from preferences and deserialize the string.

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");//get the data string
TagInformation infor = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TagInformation>(myValue); //deserialize to your class
```